# Build it already

Tags: slang

Is it correct to say “build it already” when you mean to say “just build it”. Said about a project that has not started yet. Could it be slang?

Comment: A regionalism in my neck of the woods intensifies the importance of doing something by referring to it in the past tense, as in "The grass needs cut," or "The dog needs fed." Referring to the grass-cutting and the dog-feeding as if they were already done conveys the feeling of how badly they needed to be done. In other words, you're on the grass- cutting or dog-feeding so quickly that they are virtually done already!

Answer (score 0):

It is an adverb and certainly informal when used in this manner. Dictionary.com [puts it nicely](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/already) when it describes this usage as "an intensifier to express exasperation or impatience".

```
Let's go already!
```

To answer your question, it would be correct to say "Build it already" - meaning something like "Can you just hurry up and build it!" - but this would be considered informal, yes.

Comment: Thanks, it was an informal discussion and the phrase was indeed used to express impatience